# How can I deactivate an account on my ps3?

Tags: ps3

If I deactivate an account on my PS3 system, will I be able to use the games I have downloaded on another user's account, or will it get rid of them too?

Comment: what account are you going to deactivate? is it the one where you downloaded said games from? If so then the games will be unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** I checked a bit deeper regarding this and yes, I was wrong regarding the deactivation of the account, still the same consequence as erasing the account, the games will be rendered unusable in the system(s) you deactivate your account from.

If by deactivate you mean that you're going to erase the account, then yes, every game you've got that was downloaded by that account will be disabled, that means you won't be able to use it any more since the "owner account" is not in your system any more.

Comment: deactivating an account is not deleting an account its a totally different idea

Comment: @Dupree3 thanks for the clarification, changed the answer to reflect it.